# Showing that the Maclaurin series of $(1+x)^{-\frac32}$ converges, to the funtion, for $|x|<1$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I know that I have to use Lagrange error and prove it approaches $0$ as $n → ∞$ but I do not know what to put for the $(n+1)$-th derivative of the function.

Comment: Hint: try a few derivatives and you may spot the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalized bynomial theorem.

$(a+b)^n = a^n + na^{n-1} b + \frac {n(n-1)}{2} a^{n-1}b^2+\cdots$

$c_{k+1} = \frac {c_k(n-k)}{k+1}$

This works for rational exponents, too.

$(1+x)^{-\frac 32} = 1^{-\frac 32}  - \frac 32 1^{-\frac 52}x + \frac 52\cdot\frac 32 \cdot \frac 12 1^{-\frac 72}x^2 - \frac 32\cdot\frac 52 \cdot \frac 12\cdot \frac 72\cdot \frac 13 1^{-\frac 92}x^3\cdots$

$1^{-\frac n2} = 1$

$(1+x)^{-\frac 32} = 1  - \frac 32 x + \frac {5\cdot 3}{(2^2)(2!)}x^2 - \frac {7\cdot 5\cdot 3}{(2^3)(3!)}x^3+\cdots$

$(2n+1)\cdots7\cdot 5\cdot 3 = \frac {(2n+1)!}{2^{n}n!}$

$c_n = \frac {(-1)^n(2n+1)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}$

The radius of convergence is the largest $x$ such that $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}|\frac {c_{n+1}}{c_n} x|< 1$ (the ratio test)

$|\frac {c_{n+1}}{c_n}| = \frac {(2n+3)(2n+2)}{2^2(n+1)^2}\\
\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}|\frac {c_{n+1}}{c_n}| = 1 \\
|x|<1$

Comment: I understand your answer but my question was edited so that it went from, 'converges to the function' to just plainly 'converges. If possible could you answer that question in that way?

By saying prove that it converges to the function changes what you should do I imagine. Thanks.

Comment: If $x$ is in the radius of convergence the power series converges to the function.

Comment: Oh really? In this textbook it says you have to prove that the Lagrange error goes to 0. I will take this into consideration next time. Thanks

Comment: Then you have been asked a slightly different question then I have answered.  I will add some detail when I have a little bit more time.